# Android APK generation is not picking up .so file -- why?

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk

I have an Android build environment on my Mac.  When I run `ant debug`, it cleanly packages up `libandroidnative.so` inside the APK file for deployment.  This works as expected.

I am migrating my build setup over to a Windows PC.  When I run `ant debug`, it successfully completes without packaging up `libandroidnative.so' into the APK file.

The codebases are exactly the same -- this is a pull from the same repo.  The versions of the NDK (r8) and SDK (2013-05-22) are exactly the same.

Here is a (working) output on my Mac:

```
res/layout/main.xml
AndroidManifest.xml
resources.arsc
res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png
res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
classes.dex
lib/armeabi/gdbserver
lib/armeabi/libandroidnative.so  <--- success!
lib/x86/gdbserver
lib/x86/libandroidnative.so
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/CERT.SF
META-INF/CERT.RSA
```

Here is the non-working output on my PC:

```
res/layout/main.xml
AndroidManifest.xml
resources.arsc
res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png
res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
classes.dex
lib/armeabi/gdbserver
lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
lib/x86/gdbserver
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/CERT.SF
META-INF/CERT.RSA
```

Note that the same thing happens from an Eclipse build.

Here is my Ant build file (sans comments):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="AndroidNativeLayer" default="help">

    <property file="local.properties" />

    <property file="ant.properties" />

    <property environment="env" />
    <condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
        <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
    </condition>
    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

    <fail
            message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
            unless="sdk.dir"
    />
    <import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />

    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />

</project>
```

Comment: FWIW, you have another difference: your PC is including a `lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver` that is not in the OS X edition. Are you *sure* that they are working from the same directory contents? And have you done a local `ndk-build` on the PC?

Comment: Good eye.  On my Mac, I added armeabi-v7a after checking out.  If it helps, I just did a full diff on the PC and there really are no relevant changes.  I have done a local NDK build, and the built obj file is sitting right there with an updated date stamp, ready for insertion into the apk.

Comment: Phooey. I was hoping that the `armeabi-v7` clue would help. I have no idea what may be going wrong. If you don't get any love here, you might try the `android-ndk` Google Group, if it's still around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.  TLDR; eclipse deletes the old .so file before generating the new one, **regardless of whether running ndk-build generates a new one**.  Make sure that an ndk-build command creates a new one.

In my case, I was only building if an environment variable was set to a certain value.  I had a logic branch in my Android.mk that silently exited if the environment variable was a mismatch.

On Linux/Mac, you can type `set SOME_VAR="foo"`.  In a batch file on Windows, typing set `SOME_VAR="foo"` includes the quotes in the environment variable name.

Awful and totally my fault.  I am keeping the question up because the general wisdom at the start of this question may be relevant.

Also worth understanding: you can type `aapt list bin\somepackage.apk` to generate the listings I used in the original posting.

Comment: Thanks! Michael, Google's implementation on JNI building is realy realy dirty and messy, untill now, I couldn't use android.mk to build an APK with necessary *.so files included, and no any examples to show how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/cpu_architecture, the native libraries behaved differently for different android versions.

> Android prior to 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich will only extract native libraries from a single ABI within the .apk
>
> Consequently, when targeting Android versions prior to 4.0, it is necessary to provide all native libraries for each ABI that the application will support.

and further on, it mentions that

> Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich changes the extraction logic. It will
>   enumerate all native libraries, see if the file’s basename has already
>   been extracted, and if both of the following conditions are met, then
>   the library will be extracted
>
> It hasn’t already been extracted. The native library’s ABI matches the
>   target’s primary or secondary ABI.
>
> Unfortunately, this behavior is order dependent.
>
> The native libraries are processed “in order” (as listed by, for
>   example, unzip), and the first match is extracted. Since the .apk
>   contains armeabi and armeabi-v7a versions of libtwo.so, and the
>   armeabi is listed first, it’s the armeabi version that is extracted,
>   not the armeabi-v7a version:
>
> **>  It is recommended, if the app will run on Android prior to 4.0.4,
>   that the app contain onlyarmeabi-v7a, not armeabi. Including x86 or
>   any other ABI won’t cause problems; it’s only the inclusion of both
>   armeabi and armeabi-v7a is an issue.**

and for post 4.0.4

> Android 4.0.4 changes the extraction logic: it will enumerate all
>   native libraries, read the file’s basename, then extract the primary
>   ABI version (if present), or the secondary ABI (if present). This
>   allows “merging” behavior